# Why soap operas have "soap" on the name?

Tags: word-meaning

what's with the "soap" in "soap opera"

what does "soap" refers to? does that refers to something too cheap?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. have you looked it up? Would help if you could provide your own research. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 4):

> [The] Soap opera, [a] broadcast dramatic serial program, [was] so called in the United States because most of its major sponsors for many years were manufacturers of soap and detergents.

Source: https://www.britannica.com/art/soap-opera